# Create a jQuery function with custom paragraph-text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create a function out of this? Im using append & prepend to assign elements, would like to keep this as DRY as possible and be able to customize each output text.

```
let $paragraph = $('<p>', {
    'class': 'my-class',
    text: 'some-text'
});

let $paragraph2 = $('<p>', {
    'class': 'my-other-class',
    text: 'some-other-text'
});
```

My goal is to be have a easy setup for outputing codeblocks like:

```
<p>
    Instagram
    <span class="instagram">@instagram</span>
    Twitter
    <span class="twitter">@twitter</span>
    Github
    <span class="github">@github</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept the class and text as parameters:

```
function createParagraph(cls, text) {
    return $('<p>', {
        'class': cls,
        text: text
    });
}

let $paragraph = createParagraph('my-class', 'some-text');
let $paragraph2 = createParagraph('my-other-class', 'some-other-text');
```

FWIW, `createParagraph` as an arrow function:

```
const createParagraph = (cls, text) => $('<p>', {
    'class': cls,
    text: text
});
```

---

I see you're using `let`, so assuming an ES2015+ browser. If so, you can safely leave the quotes off `class` in the object initializer. Keywords have been valid in that context since ES5. Of course, if you're transpiling for older JavaScript engines, you'll want to keep it in quotes.